# Access null value in JavaScript without using null literal

Tags: javascript, null

I'm creating a transpiler for a new programming language, named Serif. The transpiler outputs JavaScript code. Serif's grammar does not contain a null *literal*. This poses a problem: Serif is intended to be interoperable with the JavaScript ecosystem, and JavaScript APIs sometimes use the null value.

I'm looking for a reliable way to access the null value. I'm currently using `JSON.parse("null")`, which expresses my intent clearly. What are some other options? I'd like to find an approach that doesn't require a function call.

---

In Serif, `null` is an identifier. Unless shadowed, `null` provides access to the JavaScript null value. The following code demonstrates the Serif equivalent of `Object.create(null)`, and the JavaScript output.

**example.serif** (input file)

```
Object.create null;
```

**example.js** (output file)

```
const null$ = globalThis.JSON.parse("null");
Object.create(null$);
```

I'm looking for a simpler way to define `null$` in the output file. (I'm using `globalThis.JSON` rather than `JSON` so `JSON` can be used as a top-level variable in a Serif module if desired.)

Comment: Doing the equivalent of an *eval* seems like a reckless thing to encourage by design. Why not have a core function that returns a "null"? There doesn't have to be a literal to achieve this.

Comment: var myNull = void(null); XD

Comment: I want people writing Serif code to be able to use `null`, a regular *identifier*, to reference the null value. In JavaScript code this will desugar to `null$`, where `null$` is imported from Serif's prelude (standard library). The question is how to define `null` in the prelude, which is itself written in Serif.

Comment: const null = Symbol('null');
const null$ = Symbol('null');

Comment: Inventing a new null-like value is not my goal, Mathias. I need the actual null value (to provide to [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), for example).

Comment: "*How to define `null` in the prelude, which is itself written in Serif.*" - just don't write the (whole) prelude in Serif then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not that many operations that return `null` in the JS spec:

1. The final link of every prototype chain, e.g. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)` - I would recommend this for your project, since that is pretty much the definition of `null` in JS, "the missing object".
2. The "null" literal, i.e. `null`.
3. Regex matches, e.g. `/[]/.exec("")` or `"".match(/[]/)`
4. JSON parsing, e.g. `JSON.parse("null")`
5. The JSON value of invalid dates, e.g. `new Date(NaN).toJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other expressions that evaluate to `null`:

```
> /x/.exec("")
null

> "".match(/x/)
null
```

I find these less clear than `JSON.parse("null")`.